# How to solve rotational dynamics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, rotation

I am having tons of trouble solving this problem:

Two masses, m1 = 2.0 kg and m2 = 1.5 kg, are tied
together by a massless string. The string is draped over a
pulley that has a mass, M = 1.0 kg, and radius, R = 10 cm.
A fixed frictionless axle passes through the center of the
pulley. The system is released from rest.

(A) Draw the free body diagram of the pulley.

(I know how to draw the diagram)

(B) Determine the acceleration of the moving masses.

How do I use the mass/radius of the pulley??? Why is the acceleration not just the larger m1g minus the smaller m2g?? Please help.

BTW: The answer is 1.23 m/s^2

Comment: This might help move you in the right direction: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/pulley-w-two-hanging-masses.201258/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this one, I'm going to answer your question regarding the mass and radius of the pulley. The reason why the acceleration is not the larger weight minus the smaller weight is because in order for the wheel to turn, there must be a net torque on the wheel. The rope has to pull on one part of the wheel harder than the other part to cause it to rotate. It needs to rotate with an angular speed that's consistent with the linear speed of the system (hint: you're going to need a system of equations for this). Recall that $\alpha R= a$. Because of this need for the wheel to rotate, it's almost like there's a "linear equivalent mass" on the system. I actually know of a cool way to calculate a type of problem like this (any time you have an Atwoods machine).

You can do:

$$a = \frac{Net\ force\ on\ system}{m_1 + m_2 + ...m_n+\frac{I}{R^2}}$$ where you add up the masses of each block on the bottom (in this you would only have 2 masses to add up, but there could be more, that's why I said $m_n$, and then $I$ is moment of inertia of the wheel and $R$ is radius of the wheel. The net force on the system is going to be what you were saying, with the bigger weight minus the smaller weight. You can see from this equation that there's almost like this extra linear equivalent mass that's equal to $\frac{I}{R^2}$ that slows the system down.

Comment: Would the moment of inertia be for a cylinder? a disk?

Comment: It's going to be $MR^2 / 2$, just like a solid disk. :)

Comment: This is kind of breaking the rules for a comment but thank you so much for this. I have been inquiring all over the internet for hours and now I finally have a sufficient answer.

Comment: @ZacCerniglia You're very welcome! Just trying to give back to a community that has helped me so much over the years :)